# knockout automatically presses button after updating view

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, knockout.js

I have a table with `TR`bind in `foreach` loop:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: data">
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" data-bind="value: DeviceSerialNumber" required /></td>
        <td><input type="datetime" class="form-control datepicker" placeholder="Od" data-bind="value: StartDate" required /></td>
        <td><button class="btn btn-default" data-bind='click: $root.removeRow'>Delete</button></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

the button is bind to this function:

```
    self.removeRow = function (eq) {
        self.data.removeAll([eq]);
    };
```

I add data in this way:

```
var a = new Eq();
console.log(self);
a.StartDate(self.StartDateTemp());
a.DeviceId(self.DeviceTemp());
console.log(a);
console.log(self.data().length);
self.data.push(a);
console.log(self.data().length);
```

and data is:

```
var ViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.DeviceTemp = ko.observable();
    self.StartDateTemp = ko.observable();
    self.data = ko.observableArray([]);
}
```

The problem is occurring only in `IE10`. If I add anything to the data array the view is Updated. As in the view I add the is button bind to `remove` at the end of the `tr`. For unknown reason knockout or browser clicks that button and removes freshly added row.

Can You help me?

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mKvWQ/8/)

Comment: Could you create a jsfiddle to show your problem?

Comment: Error exists only in local intranet??

Comment: Yes. Only in intranet and only in IE10. In IE11 is working...

Comment: Are you sure that you are not in compatibility mode in IE?

Comment: Yes I'm sure Im in IE10Mode

Comment: @szpic I believe you are missing the `data-bind="click:$root.remove"` on your Delete button in your fiddle, maybe the reason why you don't get the error with the fiddle (I added it and found no problem in IE11 -- I do not have IE10 here). Can you confirm you get the error with IE10 and corrected fiddle?

Comment: + you did not add a ref to jquery ui causing datepickers to fail

Comment: Thanks! I updated the fiddle. Removed datepicker as its not essential in this example. And yes now this fiddle did not work in IE10. In IE11 its working

Comment: Ok, that's good to know. Unfortunately it's gonna be difficult to find a solution without being able to test. Can you try to add `return false;` after `self.data.push(a);self.Test("");`?

Comment: It was it :) Thanks! Put it as an answer and I'll accept it and upvote :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `return false` after `self.data.push(a); self.Test("");` to prevent event from bubbling:

```
self.searchKeyboardCmd = function (data, event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            if ((self.StartDateTemp() === undefined)
                || (self.number() != 1 && self.Test() != undefined)
                && (self.number() != 1 && self.Test() != "")) {

                alert("Bledna konfiguracja. Urzadzenia posiadajace numer seryjny nie moga byc dodane wiecej niz 1 raz")
                return true;
            }
            if (self.number() < 1 || isNaN(self.number())) {
                alert("Bledna ilosc");
                return true;
            }
            var a = new Eq();
            a.StorageId(self.StorageTemp());
            a.StartDate(self.StartDateTemp());
            a.DeviceSerialNumber(self.Test());
            a.DeviceId(self.DeviceTemp());
            a.Issue(self.Issue())
            a.IssueDesc(self.IssueDesc());
            a.Quantity(self.number());
            a.Project(self.Project());
            a.MeUser(self.MeUser());

            self.data.push(a);
            self.Test("");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    };
```